# Another shift/reduce conflict question for a small project

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

this is my first time working with Bison/Flex and I am stuck at the end of this project. Below are the rules that are causing the conflict. I have also attached a snippet from the output using '-v'.

```
term:
     term1
   | MINUS term1
   | IDENT LPAREN exps RPAREN 
   | IDENT LPAREN RPAREN 
   ;

term1:
     var   
   | NUMBER 
   | LPAREN exp RPAREN
   ;

var:
     IDENT LSQUARE_BRACKET exp RSQUARE_BRACKET
   | IDENT
   ;
```

This is what the output shows me:

```
57 term: IDENT . LPAREN exps RPAREN
   58     | IDENT . LPAREN R_PAREN
   64 var: IDENT . LSQUARE_BRACKET exp RSQUARE_BRACKET
   65    | IDENT .

    LPAREN           shift, and go to state 90
    LSQUARE_BRACKET  shift, and go to state 81

    LPAREN   [reduce using rule 65 (var)]
    $default  reduce using rule 65 (var)
```

I understand what is causing it, but I don't know how to fix it. I have read numerous posts about adding precedence rule, but is there another way to solve this without doing it that way?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided your full grammar. Do you use precedence rules for other operators? What is `var` used for? I could give you a highly generic solution, though.

Comment: @rici Hello! I am making simple parser for the following syntax diagrams [here](https://imgur.com/a/6ZAFSLa). I was given this as group exercise, but my partner and I are currently scratching out heads at these conflicts lol.

Comment: You say you know what the cause is, but the cause does not appear in the tiny excerpt of your grammar which you provide. The railroad diagram really doesn't help me either, since it's unambiguous afaics. In order for a reduce action to be possible where the conflict state says it is, open paren must be in FOLLOW(var). I don't see that in the RR diagram and I can't see your grammar.

Comment: @rici I am sorry that the snippet of code doesn't show the full scope of the problem. I didn't know. I have made a pastebin of both the grammar and the .output file here: [grammar](https://pastebin.com/kkXcRKeq) and [output](https://pastebin.com/5KfnFGA5). I really appreciate that there are people in this field that are willing to help. Thank you!

Comment: I'll try to find a way to answer this question tomorrow; it's not going to be easy because I don't feel that it's appropriate to write an answer based on information only found in a comment. But since I do know what the problem is, it also seems a bit cruel to not give you some sort of hint. It's evident that the rule `boolexp: relationAndExp boolexp | OR relationAndExp   ;` cannot be correct, because it allows `boolexp` to start with `or`, which would produce statements like `while or false do a := 1; end do`. That's absurd but not a parsing conflict....

Comment: But there is a conflict in there, too, because it also allows you to go derive `boolExp -> relationAndExp boolexp -> relationAndExp relationAndExp boolexp...`. If you follow through on that derivation, you'll find that `relationAndExp` can end with `var` and also can start with `(`. That's a conflict because if `var` is`IDENT`, the `(` which starts the second `relationAndExp` could also have been used with the `IDENT` as part of a function call (`IDENT '(' expression_list ')').

Comment: IMHO, you really should fix all of the algebraic expression productions. Take a look at the C or Java grammar for expressions, and compare it with yours. I think we can all agree that the C grammar is actually easier to follow, because every production with an operator also includes that operator operands. That convention makes bugs like this much easier to see immediately (and therefore they are a lot less common).

Comment: @rici I have taken a few hours to redo and re-read some lecture materials. I think I may have fixed it because I don't see any conflict. [Here is the updated grammar if you want to check it out](https://pastebin.com/vjZk9P1y). I do have a few quick (possibly very dumb) questions: 1) for the "var" grammar, why doesn't that produce a reduce/shift conflict? Both starts with "IDENT", but the compiler doesn't complain about it? 2) I read that for looping statements, we should choose to have right recursion instead of left recursion, but I don't understand that preference.

Comment: bison produces bottom-up parsers with reduce actions, not top-down grammars with predict actions. Top-down parsers can't predict if the next token could start two different productions. But reduction happens at the end of a production, so it's a recognition, not a prediction. Similarly, top-down parsers can't handle left recursion, but bottom-up parsers prefer it to right recursion. Always check which type of parser a recommendation is for.

Comment: Also, there is a minor error in some of the operator productions. You'll find that some operators which you expect to be associative don't allow it. Remember: left-associative is left recursive. Right associative is right recursive. Not associative is not recursive. Typical examples (in order): addition, exponentiation, comparison. Model (in order): A→ B | A op B; A → B | B op A; A→  B | B op B;